# shell script error

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script like this.

```
line="$@" # get the complete first line which is the complete script path 
name_of_file = ${line%.*}
file_extension = ${line##*.}
if [ $file_extension == "php"]
then
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q "$line" || ( nohup php -f "$line" > /var/log/iphorex/$name_of_file.log & ) 
fi
if [ $file_extension == "java"]
then
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q "$line" || ( nohup java -f "$name_of_file" > /var/log/iphorex/$name_of_file.log & )
fi
```

here line variable has values like `/var/www/dir/myphp.php` or `/var/www/dir/myjava.java`.

**The purpose of shell script is to check if these processes are already running** and if not i try to run them.I get the following errors.

```
name_of_file: command not found
file_extension: command not found
[: missing `]'
[: missing `]'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For the bracket issues you need spaces between the close quote `"` and the close bracket `]` like the following... `"php" ]`

Comment: What shell? Does the script start with a `#!`?

Comment: then i get `name_of_file: command not found
file_extension: command not found
[: ==: unary operator expected
[: ==: unary operator expected`

Comment: (off topic): you can replace `ps` and series of greps with simply `pgrep`. For example: `pgrep "$line" > /dev/null || your_cmd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the shell processor treats the line:

```
name_of_file = ${line%.*}
```

as the execution of the command:

```
name_of_file
```

with the parameters:

```
= ${line%.*}
```

you need to write it as:

```
name_of_file=${line%.*}
```

This makes it into a variable=value. You need to repeat this for the file_extension = line as well.

Secondly, the if:

```
if [ $file_extension == "php"]
```

has exactly the same parsing problem, you *must* have a space before the trailing ], because otherwise the parser thinks you're checking if $file_extension is equal to the string: "php]"

```
if [ $file_extension == "php" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

delete the spaces first, maybe this will help...

```
name_of_file=${line%.*}
file_extension=${line##*.}
```

**EDIT**
Try this:

```
if [ $file_extension="php" ]
..
if [ $file_extension="java" ]
```

Comment: no help ` name_of_file: command not found
infinity.sh: line 8: file_extension: command not found
infinity.sh: line 9: [: ==: unary operator expected
infinity.sh: line 13: [: ==: unary operator expected
` i got this error

Answer (score 1):

The [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273790/shell-script-error/5273915#5273915) are right that the problem in your script lies in stray spaces in your variable assignments and `[ .. ]` statements.

*(off-topic. FYI)*

I took the liberty of refactoring your script (untested!) just to highlight some alternatives, namely:

- using `pgrep` instead of `ps aux | grep .....`
- using `case`

-

```
#!/bin/bash
line="$@" # get the complete first line which is the complete script path 
name_of_file=${line%.*}

pgrep "$line" > /dev/null && exit # exit if process running

case "${line##*.}" in # check file extension
    php)
        nohup php -f "$line" > /var/log/iphorex/$name_of_file.log &
        ;;
    java)
        nohup java -f "$name_of_file" > /var/log/iphorex/$name_of_file.log &
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: @Chin:thanks for the extra stuff..looks more clean this way:)